# Order maintained when creating map from list and then creating list using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Using Java streams, we have a list of items, and for each item we want to calculate some value and then return a list of these values, using the original order. Will the following code always preserve the ordering? After all, a map is not an ordered data structure.

```
List<Item> list;
list.stream()
  .map(item -> calculateValue(item))
  .toList();
...
private double calculateValue(Item item) {
...
}
```

Comment: You aren’t creating a map. You are performing a mapping. Not the same thing.

Comment: [Javadoc for Stream.map()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) - `Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `map()` intermediate `Stream` operation does not produce a `Map` instance. It just applies the `Function` you pass to it on each element of the `Stream`. Therefore, the order of the elements of the original `List` will be preserved in the output `List`.

Comment: Thank you very much - now I clearly understand by misconception that led me to the question.

Comment: in retrospect, the question seems to be ill-posed, and also received some downvotes (and close votes). If you delete your answer, I will happily delete my question.

Comment: @Hermann.Gruber Don't, even a question based on a faulty premise is worth keeping. Others who make the same deduction you do will be grateful for your question. If something truly needs to be deleted, let the mods make that decision.

Comment: @davidalayachew thank you for your insightful comment. Agreed.